# Create a minor category selection based on the selected item in major category in python

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard

Create a minor category selection based on the selected item in major category in python

Example:
Major category = Month selection (Jan, Feb, Mar)
Minor category = Date selection (01/01/2022, 02/01/2022, 03/01/2022, ...)

```
month_category = list(df['Month'].unique())

app.layout = dbc.Container([
dbc.Row([ html.H3('Month'),
        html.Br(),
         dcc.Dropdown(id='month_dd', value= 'Jan',
                      options = [{'label':x, 'value':x} 
                                for x in month_category],
                      
                      searchable = True, search_value='',
                      placeholder= 'Please select ...'
                      
                      ),
        html.Br(),
        
        html.H3('Date'),
        html.Br(),
        
        dcc.Dropdown(id='date_dd')
        
            ])
        ])

@app.callback(
Output('date_dd','options'),
Input('month_dd', 'value')
)


def update_dd (month_dd):
      month_date= df['Month','Settlement_Date'].drop_duplicates()
      relevant_date= month_date[month_date['Month']== month_dd]['Settlement_Date'].values.tolist()
      date_option= [dict(label=x,value=x)for x in relevant_date]   

      return date_option
```

All the data are come from a .csv file. There are columns stored the related data such as Month and Date. Each date have categorized under each month.

Currently, there is no data able to select in date category (empty in the date category).

Can anyone assist on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be `df.drop_duplicates(['Month','Settlement_Date'], inplace= False)` instead of `df['Month','Settlement_Date'].drop_duplicates()`

Code:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('date_dd','options'),
    Input('month_dd', 'value')
    )


 def update_dd (month_dd):
       month_date= df.drop_duplicates(['Month','Settlement_Date'], inplace= False)
       relevant_date= month_date[month_date['Month']== month_dd]['Settlement_Date'].values.tolist()
       date_option= [dict(label=x,value=x)for x in relevant_date] 

 return date_option
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).